# How to input data in Google or-tools's TSP (Travelling Salesman Prob..)?

Tags: python, or-tools, vehicle-routing

I'm very new to Python and try to use Google's Optimization (or-)tools for solving the Travelling Salesman Problem (TSP):

https://github.com/google/or-tools/blob/1b98e19ec2b202e253d605cae2cf664abb4ae2e6/examples/python/tsp.py

I can run it and get a nice output for the random input numbers of the example, but I cannot find any way on how to input data myself. All I want to do is input a file/list with x/y coordinates. On the site

https://or-tools.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/documentation/user_manual/manual/tsp/tsp.html

they show how the input file should/can look like, but how do I implement and run that with the `tsp.py` file? It seems that, in the example, a random input is created through

> class RandomMatrix(object):   """Random matrix."""
>
> def **init**(self, size):
>       """Initialize random matrix."""
>
> ```
> rand = random.Random()
> rand.seed(FLAGS.tsp_random_seed)
> distance_max = 100
> self.matrix = {}
> for from_node in xrange(size):
>   self.matrix[from_node] = {}
>   for to_node in xrange(size):
>     if from_node == to_node:
>       self.matrix[from_node][to_node] = 0
>     else:
>       self.matrix[from_node][to_node] = rand.randrange(distance_max)
> ```
>
> def Distance(self, from_node, to_node):
>       return self.matrix[from_node][to_node]

Unfortunately, I don't even understand in what format it is created, which would be the first step to create an input myself. Later on in the code, the previously created input is used as:

> ```
> matrix = RandomMatrix(FLAGS.tsp_size)
> matrix_callback = matrix.Distance
> if FLAGS.tsp_use_random_matrix:
>   routing.SetArcCostEvaluatorOfAllVehicles(matrix_callback)
> else:
>   routing.SetArcCostEvaluatorOfAllVehicles(Distance)
> ```

I assume that this part distinguishes between a random input (which is the standard case) and a manual input, which is what I need.

Comment: Don't [cross-post](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/q/287875/110531); delete the previous question, then you don't have to mention it. Also, read [ask] and put some more effort into formatting your post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that `Matrix` is a "2-D array" that is indexed by its `from_node` and `to_node`. The nodes are numbered 0,1,..., up to number of nodes - 1.

What is stored in the matrix is the pair-wise distance between the nodes. For example, if you have three nodes, then you can set your matrix be something like: `[ [0, 3, 5], [3, 0, 7], [5, 7, 0] ]`, which represents a "triangle" map with edge lengths 3, 5, and 7.

Does this make sense to you?

Comment: Thanks a lot. That makes already a lot of sense, indeed. I was actually trying to find the content of the `Matrix` array through `dir()` or `locals()`, but it didn't appear in the list. The next big question is now where (and how) to include such a matrix in the code? I assume I have to use the `matrix` to create the `Distance` somehow, as there's another part in the code (which is active when I disable the random generation) saying

`def Distance(i, j): \\
  """Sample function.""" \\
  # Put your distance code here. \\
  return i + j`

but what variable(type/name) are they expecting?

Comment: @user56574 From the code you posted to me, it seems that `def Distance(i,j)` is a function that returns the distance between two points, based on their ID's. For example, we have three cities: 0=Chicago, 1=San Francisco, 2=New York City. Then, for example, `Distance(0,0)` should return 0, and `Distance(0,1)` should return 2000(miles), i.e. thed distance between Chicago and SF is 2000 miles; and so on. Does it make sense?

Comment: Hi Bill, it took me a while, but I believe I figured it out know. I read in a `DistMatrix` from a file now and read the values through the modified `return` command: `return float(DistMatrix[i][j])`. There are still a few flaws and things to figure out, e.g. how to forbid certain connections in order to keep that huge matrix small, but that's more an issue with the algorithm, generally I think I'm on the right track. Thanks a lot for your effort!